# Swiftmailer localhost

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I would like to send mail with symfony swiftmailer in localhost.
I have put this line in my `.env` file :

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://localhost:25
```

And I have the error :

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host localhost :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to localhost:25 (Connection refused)

Could you tell what do I have to do to send mail correctly ? (I don't want to use Gmail)

Comment: Do you have a MTA running on port 25 on you local machine?

Answer (score 4):

use MAILER_URL=null://localhost 
or you need to install and configure a local smtp server

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have understood.

Currently, I have to put the username and password in plain text in the .env file.

Is there a possibility to get the username and password at the runtime and store them in the ram instead of storing them in plain text in the .env file ?